# Javascript disabled button if checkboxes are not choosen - problem

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code, that make the button not disabled when you check at least one checkbox with class "sum".

I want to change the code, so I have to classes for and you can check only one checkbox (or two of them) to make the button not disabled.

This is what I have and it works with only one class:

```
 var checkBoxes = $('.sum');
checkBoxes.change(function () {
    $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
$('.sum').change();

    });
```

This is what I tried to do, but OR op does not work:

```
 var checkBoxes = $('.sum' || **'.checkAll'**);
checkBoxes.change(function () {
    $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
$('.sum'  || **'.checkAll'**).change();

    });
```

The code works with && operator, but I do not need this.

Comment: What do you expect the result of ORing to strings to be? Test it for yourself: `console.log('a' || 'b')`. What is the `$$` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var checkBoxes = $('.sum','.checkAll');
    checkBoxes.change(function () {
       if(checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length > 1)
           $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled',true);
       else
           $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled',false);
    });
```

Comment: @sruthi Please explain how your answer works or helps the op when answering. It's not helpful to post an answer without any context, especiually when it's a copy/paste of another answer with a slightly different code style.

Comment: Can you explain what `$('.sum','.checkAll')` does?

Comment: $selector searches for classnames class="sum" and class="checkAll" and returns the result as an array

Comment: No. `$('.sum','.checkAll') ` searches for `.sum` elements *inside* `.checkAll` elements (or maybe it just ignores the second argument since it's not an element, not sure tbh). See the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: Jquery supports multiple selectors . The .class selector can be used to select multiple classes and it works.                                  
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/
if it was $('.sum .checkAll'), then it means that it checks for all elements with className  .checkAll inside class .sum

Answer (score 5):

Using the OR operation on strings this way does not make sense. If you do this with two non-empty strings, you always get the first operand:

```js
console.log('a' || 'b')
```

In order to select [multiple elements](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), you just separate them by comma:

```
var checkBoxes = $('.sum, .checkAll');
```

---

> The code works with && operator, but I do not need this.

Not really. `'a' && 'b'` always returns `'b'`.

Comment: Thank you! I have also tried "$('.sum', .'checkAll')", but I guess it should be "$('.sum, .checkAll')" - it seem to be fine without those 2 apostrophes.

Comment: Yes, passing two arguments to jQuery means something different: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the amount of checked inputs then add/remove the disabled property in the change event handler.

```
var checkBoxes = $('.sum','.checkAll');

checkBoxes.change(function () {
    if (checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
      $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled', null);
    } else {
      $('#dashboardbuttonpay').prop('disabled');
    }
});
```

This way you capture if one or more checkboxes are checked before remove the *disabled* attribute of the button. Which lets you enable the button with either one or both checkboxes selected.

Comment: Glad that could help!